# Безопасный BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, безопасность, java

Здравствуйте!
Возникла такая проблема, приложение регистрирует broadcast reciever и он слушает некоторые события. Но вот какое дело... 
*Широковещательные сигналы могут быть посланы любым приложением, исполняющимся под управлением операционной системы Android* 
Хочу сделать более безопасным приложение. Насколько нагуглил, есть вариант писать свои кастомные "события" ( ACTION), и `IntentFilter` . Насколько это безопаснее?
Главный вопрос, в том, как реализовать более безопасный  `Broadcast reciever` , чтобы злоумышленик не смог ( или ооочень напрягся), перехватить мои сигналы.

```
BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            if(intent.getAction().equals(MyApplication.ACTION_LOGOUT)) {
                Log.d("aaa", "Inactivity timeout reached. Finishing...");
                finish();

                Toast.makeText(AutologoutActivity.this, R.string.strInactivityTimerExpired, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else if(intent.getAction().equals(MyApplication.ACTION_TERMINATE_SESSION)) {
                Log.d("aaa", "Session terminated. Finishing...");
                finish();
                Toast.makeText(AutologoutActivity.this, R.string.strSessionTerminated, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Достаточно объявить ваш `BroadcastReceiver` `android:exported=false` и до него не смогут достучаться извне приложения. [пруфлинк](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/receiver-element.html)

Comment: `BroadcastReceiver` у меня в коде зарегистрирован ( на в манифесте).
Как установить  `exported=false` для него, ненагуглил.

Comment: А что мешает его зарегистрировать в манифесте? Если так хотите в коде, тогда надо использовать [LocalBroadcastManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html)

Comment: @Barmaley ♦ перенес все в манифест